# How to Integrate Azure AD authentication with custom Role store in .net core mvc?

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-3.1

I have web application created with .net core mvc, and enabled azure AD authentication and , has postgress database with roles and user table.

`Startup.cs` is as bellow

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

        ValidateToken(services);

        services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });

        services.AddRazorPages();

        //ConfigureElsa(services);

        ConfigureDatabaseContext(services);
        ConfigurePolicies(services);
        ConfigureHandlers(services);
    }
```

I have registered app in azure portal and all is working fine.

I need to know how to integrate this with my existing database **roles**.

Does anyone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the best fit for your scenario is the [app roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkBVY.png) feature in the Azure ad. Here is a [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) that demonstrates how you can define roles and also use attributes in your asp.net core classes to perform AuthZ based on the roles claim.
You can leverage the MS Graph API's [application patch endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to dynamically add app roles. Just write a utility program to import the app roles from your local roles database and hit the endpoint to patch your app registration with the new app roles.
Here is a sample patch request.

```
URL https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/3e7d226f-2c9b-4d28-b3ce-6a9353753hah

{
    "appRoles": [
        {
            "allowedMemberTypes": [
                "User",
                "Application"
            ],
            "description": "TestRole",
            "displayName": "TestRole",
            "id": "6cd9c306-9252-4092-b52a-960016053356",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "origin": "Application",
            "value": "TestRoles"
        }
    ]
}
```

please note that the following are the permission requirements.
[image]

The following PowerShell script will enable you to create app roles in existing application registrations

```
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId <TenantId>
# Create an Azure AD role of given name and description
Function CreateAppRole([string] $Name, [string] $Description)
{
$appRole = New-Object Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.AppRole
$appRole.AllowedMemberTypes = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
$appRole.AllowedMemberTypes.Add(“User”);
$appRole.AllowedMemberTypes.Add(“Application”);
$appRole.DisplayName = $Name
$appRole.Id = New-Guid
$appRole.IsEnabled = $true
$appRole.Description = $Description
$appRole.Value = $Name;
return $appRole
}
# ObjectId for application from App Registrations in your AzureAD
$appObjectId = “<ObjectId>”
$app = Get-AzureADMSApplication -ObjectId $appObjectId
$appRoles = $app.AppRoles
Write-Host “App Roles before addition of new role..”
Write-Host $appRoles
$newRole = CreateAppRole -name “NewApplicationName” -description “New application description”
$appRoles.Add($newRole)
Set-AzureADMSApplication -ObjectId $app.Id -AppRoles $appRoles
```

If this solution helped you please mark it as verified.

Comment: But if i want to add more customizable solution,?

Comment: What is the customization that you want?

Comment: How that explain integration with existing roles in postgres?